# How to put two input fields in angular align horizontal?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I need to put two input fields with labels as below.

[image]

But In using angular, some data R fields related input is not visible. Then, it should be like the below.
[image]

My code

```
    <div>
  <div>
    <label i18n="k" *ngIf="model" id="'k'">
      <br />
      <br />
      K:
      {{model.k}} </label>
    <label i18n="N" *ngIf="model"
      id="'N'">
      <br />
      <br />
      N:
      {{model.n}} </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <mat-form-field [formGroup]="DetailForm">
      <label *ngIf="isVisible(model.r)">R</label>
      <input *ngIf="isVisible(model.r)" matInput formControlName="rate"
        [type]="'number'" [placeholder]="'rate'" [required]="false" [readonly]="false" [spaced]="false">
      <label>Comment</label>
      <input matInput formControlName="c" [type]="'text'" [placeholder]="'comment'" [required]="false"
        [readonly]="false" [spaced]="false">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I tried a different way when two inputs are available it shows like the one below.

[image]

need some expert help to resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use 2 different mat-form-fields like this:

```html
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Rate</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Comment</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
      </mat-form-field>
```

Or have a look at this stackblitz, i put a very small demo of the above changes there:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-r7khp2